# Why factorial function return not 1?

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why the function returned a result and not a unit, how does it work?

```
function factorial(n) {
  return (n != 1) ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1;
}

console.log(factorial(5)); // result is 120 why not 1 ?
```

Comment: What's the problem ? 5 factorial is 120. The function is recursive. Everything looks fine to me

Comment: Why do you think `factorial(5)` should return the value 1?

Comment: it can return 1, if you set n to 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Comment: Step through manually - at start, `n==5` so n!=1 so returns `(n * facorial(n-1))` - ie `n * factorial(4)` - `factorial(4)` at start, `n==4` so `n!=1` so ... etc when n does == 1, it returns 1 with no more recursive calls and goes back up to the stack until it gets to the original (5) and returns that value.

Comment: Try stepping through your code with a debugger, like the one in your browser dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive function. You start by passing in `5`. It then calls itself with `4`, and so on. The math for each call looks like this:

```
factorial(5): 5 * factorial(4)
factorial(4): 4 * factorial(3)
factorial(3): 3 * factorial(2)
factorial(2): 2 * factorial(1)
factorial(1): 1
```

Once you get to the "base case", 1, execution goes back up the stack in reverse order and uses the result of each previous step:

```
factorial(1): 1
factorial(2): 2 * 1 = 2
factorial(3): 3 * 2 = 6
factorial(4): 4 * 6 = 24
factorial(5): 5 * 24 = 120
```

And so factorial(5) returns 120.